# Debugging an eclipse within another eclipse - Eclipse Trader

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

According to this  [link](http://www.eclipsetrader.org/wiki/DevelopmentSetup)

It seems easy to setup the environment. Into the last paragraph:

> Setup the Run Configuration

There should be a misterious EclipseTrader run configuration appearing from nowhere !!

Obviously there is no such thing !!

The question is, how can I debug an eclipse within another elipse ?? Is it possibile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the `Eclipse application` entry in the available debug configurations then you should probably be running an Eclipse which does not have the [plug-in development environment (PDE)](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) installed.

You can either download the `Eclipse classic` package which already contains PDE from the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or install the PDE plug-ins in your current Eclipse platfom from the Eclipse update sites.

Comment: Yes , there was also a prob with my java X64 and eclipse X86 mismatch on my pc !!!